# Firebase argument contains undefined property

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create new  channels for my chat application  using react.js and firebase  on the server side, but I cannot understand the error.

I have tried crosschecking the code but I can't see the error, the server runs well but the data doesn't save, firebase throws an exception

```
addChannel = () => {
    const { channelsRef, channelName, channelDetails, user } = this.state;

    const key = channelsRef.push().key;

    const newChannel = {
      id: key,
      name: channelName,
      details: channelDetails,
      createdBy: {
        name: user.displayName,
        avatar: user.photoURL
      }
    };
```

"failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'channels.-Lom5uOsqFhKGqH6KW5b.createdBy.name.currentUser.location.state'"

Comment: Exactly which line here is causing the issue?  What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: @DougStevenson   this line is the one that is causes the error ("Channels.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined"), I want new channels to contain the creators userName and their avatar.     createdBy: {
              name: user.displayName,
        avatar: user.photoURL
      }

Comment: I don't see any code here that matches that error.  When posting on Stack Overflow, it's important to be able to narrow down the problem to the line of code that you've written that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson the server runs without any errors , the problem is on the  back end ie fire base, when I try to add a new channel firebase  throws an exception "  displayName name is undefined"

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show how you interact with Firebase. Please make sure that your question include exactly enough (nothing more, nothing less) to allow us to reproduce your problem as easily as possible. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).